# Converting a Multi-word search string for use in MySQL FULLTEXT Boolean mode

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, full-text-search

I am using Innodb's FTS feature for searching my database and returning the results sorted by relevancy. When using Boolean mode, the search string must be connverted to a form where the individual terms must be seperated by some operators like `+`, `~`, `-`, `*`.

If I have a search string with multiple word, how can I (using PHP perhaps) to convert the search string so I can use it with the `MATCH()... .AGAINST()` clause?

**Search term:**

`stack over flow`

**SQL Query**:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
    MATCH ( name, description) 
    AGAINST ('+*stack* +*over* +*flow*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);"
```

**Matched results**

```
stack over flow
haystack hover flowers
```

Comment: explode() on space then rebuild as required

Comment: Can boolean mode returns the relevancy score? If not, does natural language mode returns the relevancy score and also phrases not in the same order as in the search string?

Comment: 'relevancy score" yes it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for fuzzy search i do:

```
$search_words = explode(' ', $search);
foreach ($search_words as $foo) {
    $sql_search .= '*' . $foo . '* ' ;
}
```

or regular:

```
$search_words = explode(' ', $search);
$sql_search = '+' . implode(" +", $search_words);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'stack over flow';

$string = preg_replace('#\b(\S+)\b#', '+*\\1*', $string); # \b can be ommited

echo $string; # +*stack* +*over* +*flow*
```

One of the solutions, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dagon I wouldn't argue with that.